# Issue Converting Matlab Code to Python when trying to sum array

Tags: python, numpy

I am converting a Matlab code to Python but facing an issue in below lines:

Code:

Matlab:

```
P_asef_t = sum(P_asef);
P_aseb_t = sum(P_aseb);
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

P_asef_t = np.sum(P_asef)
P_aseb_t = np.sum(P_aseb)
```

Matlab

```
whos P_asef
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        P_asef     51x1200                  489600  double

Total is 61200 elements using 489600 bytes
```

And in Python:

```
(Pdb) P_asef.shape, P_asef.size
((51, 1200), 61200)
```

But variable **P_asef_t** comparatively is coming completely incorrect:

MATLAB:

```
debug> whos P_asef_t
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name          Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====          ====                     =====  ===== 
        P_asef_t      1x1200                    9600  double

Total is 1200 elements using 9600 bytes

debug>  P_asef_t
P_asef_t =

 Columns 1 through 6:

   1.2208e-11   9.9358e-03   9.8720e-03   9.8087e-03   9.7457e-03   9.6831e-03

 Columns 7 through 12:

   9.6210e-03   9.5592e-03   9.4978e-03   9.4368e-03   9.3762e-03   9.3160e-03

 Columns 13 through 18:
```

Python:

```
(Pdb) P_asef_t
1.3898510532602344
(Pdb) P_asef_t.shape, P_asef_t.size
((), 1)
(Pdb)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's [sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) function takes an additional argument `axis`, that defines over which axis of the array is summed. The problem here is that is defaults to summing over all axes.

In the case of a matrix such as `P_asef` you have two axes. The 0th axis are the columns and the 1st are the rows. If you only want to sum along columns, you need to tell `sum` to only sum over `axis=0`.

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.ones((51,1200))
mat1 = np.sum(mat,axis=0)
mat2 = np.sum(mat,axis=1)
mat3 = np.sum(mat)
```